# SQL select latest news

Tags: php, sql

I want to present the 5 latest news on my website based on the date. How would that work? So when a new article is posted, it would push the oldest one out of the website and not show it but still keep it in the database.

Thanks

Comment: Have you even google it? Also please tag RDBMS. In MYSQL try order by date desc and LIMIT

Comment: ANSI SQL: `... ORDER BY datecolumn DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You've already got one product specific answer. Don't waste other users's time writing answers for "wrong" products.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

This might help you.
* MYSQL

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.